# How to insert a pause in Photoshop batch process?

Tags: photoshop, batch

I am editing photos with a batch process in Photoshop with autosave turned off. When I go through the photos, I cannot actually preview the changes because it closes too fast. Is there a way to tell the batch process to pause or wait so the editor can view the changes as they go through the stack of images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert a "Stop" action anywhere you want.  It doesn't actually stop the batch, but pauses it.  See the section "Insert a stop" at [Creating actions](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-actions.html#creating_actions) in Adobe's [Photoshop User Guide](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/user-guide.html).